# Notify user when the call is answered by other party

Tags: android

Assume there are two users, A and B. When A calls to B, A should be notified with a toast message when B has answered A's call.

I am able to identify only `RINGING`, `IDLE`, `OFFHOOK states.

The state when call is

1. connecting to B and
2. when connected

both come under `OFFHOOK` state only. I would like to differentiate the point when the call is exactly answered.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no API supporting this option you want. In other words, there is currently no way to know programattically when user B has answered your call.

Sorry!

Comment: But I have seen in NQ mobile security application they have notified user by making a milli second vibration when call is answered!

Comment: True, I have this in my Samsung phone too. But that is a Vendor-specific API created and implemented by the phone vendor - that we (the public) do not have access to.